# NFS Most Wanted 2005 graphics issue: display is flickering randomly

Tags: technical-issues, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

I've installed NFS MW 2005, but unfortunately it's impossible to play because of weirdly flickering screen with randomly and quickly appearing and disappearing horizontal stripes.
It's difficult to capture this screen state as taken screenshots don't showcase this issue, but here is a photo of it:

[image]

**Any idea what might be the issue?**

I've tried updating NVidia GPU Drivers, but to no avail.

**Config:** 
Laptop: MSI GE62 2QE Apache; 
CPU: i7-4720hq; 
GPU: GTX965M, 2GB; 
RAM: 16 GB; 
OS: Windows 10 64-bit, v. 1803; 
NVidia driver version: 430.86 
Directx: 12

Comment: Looks like a corrupted installation. Have you tried reinstalling the game?

Comment: If screenshots don't show the artifacts, it may not be a software issue. [Would a GPU artifact show up on a screenshot?](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/4fkw8t/would_a_gpu_artifact_show_up_on_a_screenshot/)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Yes, I've reinstalled it a couple of times

Comment: @RoijanEskor But how come in this case there are no similar issues in all possible other use cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that running the game with the discrete graphics card only instead of system default mode which uses both Intel HD 4600 and Nvidia GTX965M did the trick.

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Set Vsync on, get to the settings screen, push 2 for advanced settings then push vsync on.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the game properties, that is `speed.exe` properties, go to the Compatibility tab, then make these properties the same as mine:

1. Check the 'Run this Program in Compatibility mode' & select any compatibility mode. Try out different OSes, like Windows 98, Windows 7. Windows 7 compatibility mode worked for me.
2. Check the 'Disable Full Screen Optimizations'
3. Check the 'Run this program as an Administrator'
   Now your game won't flicker. Good day!

[image]